# How to make picklist editable in the target component in angular?

Tags: html, angular, primeng, picklist

I am using `p-picklist` and I want to edit target list span data used for displaying the value.

I am using the source code: https://primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/picklist

How can I make product name editable in the target list.

```html
<p-pickList
  [source]="sourceProducts"
  [target]="targetProducts"
  sourceHeader="Available"
  targetHeader="Selected"
  [dragdrop]="true"
  [responsive]="true"
  [sourceStyle]="{'height':'30rem'}"
  [targetStyle]="{'height':'30rem'}"
  filterBy="name"
  sourceFilterPlaceholder="Search by name"
  targetFilterPlaceholder="Search by name"
>
  <ng-template let-product pTemplate="item">
    <div class="product-item">
      <div class="image-container">
        <img
          src="assets/showcase/images/demo/product/{{product.image}}"
          [alt]="product.name"
          class="product-image"
        />
      </div>
      <div class="product-list-detail">
        <h5 class="p-mb-2">{{product.name}}</h5>
        <i class="pi pi-tag product-category-icon"></i>
        <span class="product-category">{{product.category}}</span>
      </div>
      <div class="product-list-action">
        <h6 class="p-mb-2">${{product.price}}</h6>
        <span
          [class]="'product-badge status-' + product.inventoryStatus.toLowerCase()"
          >{{product.inventoryStatus}}</span
        >
      </div>
    </div>
  </ng-template>
</p-pickList>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turning the `<h5 class="p-mb-2">{{product.name}}</h5>` into an input with `[(ngModel)]="product.name"` seem to work.

In order to check if the templated item is listed under `target` and not under `source`, you can check the element's position on the DOM; if it is inside `.p-picklist-target`, show the `input`, else show `h5`.

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-picklist-demo-mrcv2y?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)